# xpath simple_html_dom_parser

Tags: xpath, simple-html-dom

Не получается получить xpath от этой странички и подобных http://pornolab.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2370609
В браузере xpath работает, но когда в simple_html_dom_parser пытаешься получить эти данные, он ничего не выдает или не то что нужно.
Пробовал уже много вариантов.
Этот в браузере работает, а в simple_html_dom_parser - пусто:

```
//*[@class="post_body"]/span/text()[1]
```

Как же мне получить значения: Имя актрисы, Название ролика итд.?

Comment: а как вообще связаны `Simple HTML DOM` и `XPath` ?

Comment: @teran, она поддерживает поиск по xPath.